# Linking separate projects in GHC

Tags: haskell, ghc

Ok this should be simple, but can't seem to figure this out. I have two projects, ProjectA and ProjectB. ProjectB depends on the old project, ProjectA. Now I want to build ProjectB. And I do not want to change the directory structure for ProjectA now. Problem is, I always used -outputdir bin with ProjectA.

ProjectA looked like this:

```
ProjectA/
  bin/
    (*.o, *.hi in proper paths, sometimes also *.p_o and *.p_hi)
  Foo/
    ModuleX.hs
  ModuleA.hs
  ModuleB.hs
```

Now I have a different folder with ProjectB, with its own separate -outputdir. I just need to link to the old project object files (without having ProjectA files recompiled). I realize that I can probably cabalize ProjectA ... but is there no simpler way?

Comment: it seems to me that you need a build system. If you don't like cabal (or makefiles) try shake (http://community.haskell.org/~ndm/shake/)

Comment: Thanks, I will check out shake, but I don't really need a make replacement. In fact, I am quite a happy user of make right now. The problem is that GHC seems to have this strange way of searching for .o and .hi files that doesn't seem to be sufficiently customizable.

In other words, if I add -outputdir bin ... it will look for precompiled files in bin, and I can't find a way to change that to ProjectA/bin

Answer (score 2):

The "simple way" is to use Cabal. Once you've installed Project A, you never need to worry about where the hell it's actually stored ever again; GHC will just find it.

If you don't want to do this, try using the `-i` switch to GHC to tell what folders to search for your compiled stuff.

http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.1/html/users_guide/separate-compilation.html

Comment: I already tried -i before posting this. Does everything I want, except it also recompiles everything in ProjectA. I was hoping to find an analogue for 'gcc x.o y.o'.

Comment: And as for Cabal, that works, but I don't want to drop this in my ~/.cabal folder when I will only be using this for 2-3 Projects. I don't want this to be in my search path for every project ever.

Comment: Interesting. The documentation claims that in `--make` mode, it'll look for _source_ files in the specified directory, but otherwise it'll look for interface (and presumably object) files. Of course, since GHC 7 (?) `--make` mode is now always the default, and I'm not sure how to turn it off...

Comment: Also, when you say "old project", was it compiled with the same version of GHC? Because if not, then you have no choice but to recompile.

Comment: @Savui, if you don't want to pollute your `~/.cabal`, check out [cabal-dev](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cabal-dev)

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid,: Yes, it was the same GHC version

Comment: @luqui: I think cabal-dev solved all my problems. I know I was complaining about separate compilation, but I guess what I was really worried about was being unable to have multiple development versions of ProjectA while have ProjectB depend only on the stable versions.

Comment: You could also take a look at [cabal-meta](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cabal-meta) which could help building project with local dependencies right form the sources (and may use `cabal-dev` to prevent polluting `~/.cabal`)